# Showing as much of a scrollable section as possible in HTML

Tags: html, css

I would like a certain area on my page to be scrollable. The code below does just that. However, I would like the scrollable area to stretch its height to however long the screen size is, so that the max amount of the scrollable area can be viewed for the given screen size.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:lightgrey; overflow:hidden">
    <div id="nav">
        London<br>
        Paris<br>
        Tokyo<br>
    </div>

    <div class="page-wrap">
        <h1>Reporting System</h1>

        <h3 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Find a
        Student</h3><br>

        <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>

            <h2><legend>Details</legend></h2><legend></legend>

            <form class="pure-form" onsubmit="return false;">
                <label>Last Name &nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input autofocus="" class=
                "lastname" id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text"><br>
                <br>
            </form>
        </fieldset><br>

        <div class="buttonAlign">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="button-error pure-button" onclick=
            "cancel();" type="button" value="Clear"> <input class=
            "button-secondary pure-button" id="button" type="button" value=
            "View ALL"> <input class="button-secondary pure-button" id=
            "button1" type="button" value="Search">
        </div><br>
        <br>

        <div id="info"></div><br>

        <div style="overflow-y : auto; max-height: 250px; width: 100%;">
            <div id="comments"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you need to post the rest of your code so we can see where this <div> tag is nested.

Answer (score 0):

This ones always a doozy.  What I have found to be the best method for this is use position absolutes.

```
<body style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    ....
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 12px;left:12px;right:12px;bottom:12px;height:100%;overflow-y:scroll">
    ....
</body>
```

Also, I would suggest using `overflow-y:auto`, and that way you only get the scroll when needed.  I find it seems to sit better with people.

See if that works better for you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your full source code... but here is an example I made showing you the concept.

[Here is the **JSfiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rk4c927j/)

Screenshot:

[image]

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div>
            <div id="logo">Reporting System</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="srchbar" type="search" placeholder="Search by last name...">
            <div id="srchbtn" class="form-btn btn-black"><span>search</span></div>
        </div>        
        <div>
            <a href="#">London</a>
            <a href="#">Paris</a>
            <a href="#">Tokyo</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="main">
        <article id="container">
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
            <div class="result">result data from database...</div>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
nav{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;

    z-index: 999;
    background: #1E67CB;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
nav>div{
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center; 
}
#logo{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    margin-left: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    line-height: 1.43;  
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: Circular,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
#srchbar{
    height: 30px;
    width: 400px;
    border: none;
    color: #7C7C7C;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
    cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);

}
#srchbtn{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#srchbtn>span{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    color: #fff;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}
nav>div{
    width: 50vw;    
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(1){
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(2){
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(3){
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
nav>div>a{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;

    margin: 0 .5em;
    padding: 0.6em 1.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-transition: background-color 100ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 100ms;
    transition: background-color 100ms;
}
nav>div>a:hover{
     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}
nav>div>a:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#main{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    overflow: scroll;
/*  margin: 60px 0; */
    background: #ccc;
}
#container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    overflow: scroll;
    background: #fff;

    max-width: 1280px;
    width: 100%;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
.result{    
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer;    

    min-width: 1280px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.result:hover{
    background: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.46);
}
footer{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;

    z-index: 999;
    background: #1E67CB;

    box-shadow: 0 -1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.form-btn{
    width: 22.1em;  
    color: #FFF;
    align-self: center;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form-btn:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); 
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.btn-black{
    background: #767575;
}
.btn-black:hover{
    background: #828282;
}
```

Comment: I tried making this work with my code. Any chance you could post an answer with edits to my code? Thanks!

Comment: @SamG okay I just took a look at your code... everything looks fine you just don't have any content inside the container. Inspect element on (#comments) id in your code and add "min-height: 200vh" then try scrolling you will see the scrollbar on the right side.

Comment: I know how to get the scroll bar there. I want the scroll bar to always reach the bottom of the page, so if you're viewing the page on a big screen, you can view more with having to scroll less.

Comment: @SamG ahhh okay yea give me sec I'm making a little better version ;D